# How to manipulate my string using regex in php?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string as below

```
$str = '"Mark Zuckerberg" facebook "A social utility connecting friends" profile';
```

I want it to be manipulated as follows

```
$output = '"Mark Zuckerberg" OR facebook OR "A social utility connecting friends" OR profile';
```

What I am trying to have in output is all the units combined with OR in between them. Here a unit is wither a single word when its not in double quotes or the complete string that falls within the single quotes.

I wanted to try with preg_replace. But am unable to get a correct regular expression to match. Kindly help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/ (?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/', ' OR ', $subject);
```

works if you don't have any escaped quotes in your string. It replaces spaces only if they are followed by an even number of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why preg_replace rather than a simple

```
$output = '"'.implode('" OR "',str_getcsv($str,' ')).'"';
```